# Are there composite numbers matching the conditions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Conditions:

> n such that $\ Ord_n(2) \mid n-1 $ and $\ Ord_n(2) - 1 = 2^x,n \in    >2\mathbb{N}+1,\ x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.

I check up to 1e7 :

```
3,7,31,73,6151,57457,131071,599479,1572871,2252951,5242921
```

Numbers matching the condition are all primes.Are there composite numbers matching the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: $n = 1227133513 = 23 \cdot 89 \cdot 599479$ appears to be the smallest, having $\text{ord}_n(2) = 33$.  However, there seems to be no further examples up to $10^{20}$.  It's not surprising that they are very rare, since pseudoprimes are already much rarer than the primes.

Comment: Thanks for your check.Up to $\ 2^{64}\ $ they say there are $\ 118968378\ $ pseudoprimes,see: http://www.janfeitsma.nl/math/psp2/statistics